# ¿Por que no me funciona el [DataType(DataType.Password)]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, data-atributos

Tengo un modelo `CredencialesViewModel` el cual tiene un propiedad `Pwd` tipo `string` le agregue el decorador de tipo de dato, pero en la vista no me renderiza un `input type password` si no que uno de tipo texto.

¿Por que sera esto?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código razor? como lo estas renderizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si definís el `ViewModel` de la siguiente manera

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Pass word is required")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Según tu versión de MVC, si es más nueva, deberías, simlemente usar `@EditorFor()`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"}})
```

y en caso de que sea un poco más vieja

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"})
```

Esta respuesta está basada en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329997/create-password-field-html-textboxfor) publicación de StackOverflow en Inglés.

Saludos y éxitos!

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio